# Is it possible to institute a timeout for SKStoreProductViewController loadProductWithParameters?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, ios6, app-store

I'm currently calling storeViewController loadProductWithParameters via dispatch_async . Is it possible to set a timeout value so it only tries to fetch the results for X seconds and then gives up?

Comment: Any luck getting a solution?

Comment: @Leonardo - I didn't but Alexis Pribula has a possible solution if you want to test it.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented my own timeout by using with the class method below instead of calling loadProductWithParameters directly. It times out thanks to a `dispatch_after` and `__block` variable.

```
+ (void)loadProductViewControllerWithTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout
                      storeKitViewController:(SKStoreProductViewController *)storeKitViewController
                                  parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                           completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL result, NSError *error))completionHandler {

  __block BOOL hasReturnedOrTimedOut = NO;

  [storeKitViewController loadProductWithParameters:parameters completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      if (!hasReturnedOrTimedOut) {
        hasReturnedOrTimedOut = YES;
        if (completionHandler) completionHandler(result, error);
      }
    });
  }];

  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(timeout * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (!hasReturnedOrTimedOut) {
      hasReturnedOrTimedOut = YES;
      if (completionHandler) completionHandler(NO, nil); // Or add your own error instead of |nil|.
    }
  });
}
```

My latest app update got rejected by Apple because loadProductWithParameters never called its completionBlock and stopped my users from buying songs on iTunes... Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not doing much iOS dev but if I get a chance to test it I will.

Answer (score 0):

I have acomplished it like so:

```
  __block BOOL timeoutOrFinish = NO;

  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(30 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if(!timeoutOrFinish) {
      timeoutOrFinish = YES;
      [self dismissAndShowError];
    }
  });

  [storeViewController loadProductWithParameters:parameters completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if(timeoutOrFinish) {
      return;
    }

    timeoutOrFinish = YES;
    //[[NetworkManager sharedManager] showNetworkActivityIndicator:NO];
    if(error) {
      [self dismissAndShowError];
    }
  }];

  [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:storeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

where `dismissAndShowError` method runs `dismissViewControllerAnimated` and shows alert with an error.

Basically, you have a separate timer (30 seconds in my case) that switches a flag. After that time, if store has still not been loaded, I close it and display an error. Otherwise, completion is called (on cancel, finish and error) and handles all actions according to the status.